# Why aren't my Laplace transform and Undetermind Coefficients answers matching up?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I might be losing my mind this morning (I am, for sure), but I can't these two techniques to give me the same answer to a basic differential equations problem.

The problem is $y''-8y'+27y=0$ with the initial conditions $y(0)=-8$ and $y'(0)=5$.  Using Laplace transforms, I get the solution $y=\frac{69}{\sqrt{11}}e^{4t}\sin(\sqrt{11}t)-8e^{4t}\cos(\sqrt{11}t)$, which is wrong.

If I use Undetermined Coefficients, I get $y=\frac{37}{\sqrt{11}}e^{4t}\sin(\sqrt{11}t)-8e^{4t}\cos(\sqrt{11}t)$, which is right.

The problem is that I can't find my mistake with the LT technique.  The process is straight forward enough:

$\mathcal{L}(y''-8y'+27y)=\mathcal{L}(s^2-8s+27)-s(-8)-5+8(-8)=\mathcal{L}(s^2-8s+27)+8s-69=0$

$\mathcal{L}(y)=\frac{69-8s}{s^2-8s+16+11}=\frac{69-8s}{(s-4)^2+11}$

Then I split up the fraction, scale by $\frac{69}{\sqrt{11}}$ for the $\sin$ term and I'm done.  The $\cos$ term is right, but that 69 is the bugaboo for some reason. Please point out the idiotic thing I missed!

Comment: Can you explain this equality? $$\mathcal{L}(y''-8y'+27y)=\mathcal{L}(s^2-8s+27)-s(-8)-5+8(-8)$$ I thought the $\mathcal{L}$ was dropped after the transformation

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal{L}(y)$ is correctly computed. Your error is in computing the inverse Laplace transform:
$$
\frac{69-8\,s}{(s-4)^2+11}=\frac{37}{(s-4)^2+11}-\frac{8(s-4)}{(s-4)^2+11}.
$$

Comment: Oh!!!! On the cosine portion, I translated the $s$ by 4 on the bottom, but neglected to on the top!  Ugh.  Thank you so much.